# Having trouble reading in user input data for a program which counts the number of occurrences of letters in a string

Tags: c

The code seems to only count one of the occurances when using scanf() or a defined getChar() I have set up but will count all and display when the string is defined in code. How can I get the output to work correctly while having a user input.

I've tried a few different approaches at taking the user input as seen but still I don't seem to be getting the result desired.

```
//#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

  char *s;

 fgets(&s[0],98,stdin);
  int letter_counts[26] = {0};
  int length = strlen(s);
  char c;
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    c = toupper(s[i]);
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
      letter_counts[c - 'A']++;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    if (letter_counts[i] > 0) {
      printf("%c%d ", 'A' + i, letter_counts[i]);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I've Now changed it to use the fgets() but I don't seem to be using that correctly either...

Comment: Did not realise the screencap i had attached got taken off my b

Comment: To start with.... Fix all warnings that your compiler gave you. If you didn't get any warnings it's time to increase the warning level of the compiler. For `gcc` you should at least do: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror program.c`

Comment: You should get 3 important warnings that clearly indicates what is wrong with the current code

Comment: If you want to read a line of user input, use the function `fgets` but notice that `fgets` also read newline characters.

Comment: I'm using replit right now and its been working for everything to now but I'll consider moving towards something more rounded.

Comment: `char *s;` --> `char s[100];`

Comment: What you need to learn is that a pointer by itself can't store any data! A pointer must point to some other memory where the data can be stored. Your `s` pointer is not pointing to any valid memory so your program will fail. What you could do is `char *s = malloc(100);` to get some valid memory... **But** use a char array instead - in this case it is much easier

Comment: OT: For arrays code like `&s[0]` is the same as just `s`

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you don't allocate any space to `s`.  Also introduces a couple of constants instead of your magic values for size:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ALPHA_LEN 'Z' -'A' + 1
#define STR_LEN 98

int main() {
    char s[STR_LEN+1];
    if(!fgets(&s[0],STR_LEN+1, stdin)) {
        printf("gets failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int letter_counts[ALPHA_LEN] = {0};
    size_t length = strlen(s);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char c = toupper(s[i]);
        if (isupper(c))
            letter_counts[c - 'A']++;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof letter_counts / sizeof *letter_counts; i++) {
        if (letter_counts[i]) {
            printf("%c%d ", 'A' + i, letter_counts[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```